# Using exec -a in Script

Tags: bash, shell, exec

Hi I'm trying to run the following script. However, I get an error. Any tips?
prog1 takes in an argument in this case 1000. I am using the exec command because I want to change the program name to "/bin/grade" when executing prog1.

This is the error I am getting:
/script.sh: 2: exec: -a: not found

```
#! /bin/sh
exec -a "/bin/grade" ./prog1 1000 &
sleep 0.001
kill -14 $!
```

Comment: /script.sh: 2: exec: -a: not found

Answer (score 0):

Run the script with bash instead of bash instead of sh - put #!/bin/bash at the top. The -a flag is specific to the bash shell.

Example A:

```
#!/bin/sh 

exec -a "/bin/bash" pwd
```

Returns: `./test.sh: 3: exec: -a: not found`

Example B:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec -a "/bin/sh" pwd
```

Returns: `/home/dev`